# Fill javascript object dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using [responsive calendar](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/) in a mvc project.
When setting up the calendar, I need to fill an object called events with my data.

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
            time: '@DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()' + '-' + '@DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()',
            events: { //object to fill with my model data
            "2013-04-30": { "number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider" },
            "2013-04-26": { "number": 1, "url": "http://w3widgets.com" },
            "2013-05-03": { "number": 1 },
            "2013-06-12": {},
            "2015-06-12": { "number": 1 }
       }
  });
```

However this object isn't an array. How to achieve this

Update :
My model is a list of DateEvents :

```
class DateEvents 
{ 
    DateTime Date {get;set;} 
    int Count {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What structure would you like the array to have?

Comment: You can add `key` and `value` in `Object`.. What is the question ?

Comment: I suggest you to add some information about your model data to your question.

Comment: You can do `events[key] = value`.

Comment: have you tried adding [] in your code? That's how you make a array

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array with data, but must supply it like in your example in the 'events' property, you can create an object like below.

```
var myEvents = {};
myEvents["2013-04-30"] = { "number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider" };
```

If you can do this for one item, you can do this also in a loop (forEach) to get the data from an existing source (array?) and add it to the myEvents object. After completion of 'myEvents', you can set the value of 'events' of the responsiveCalendar to 'myEvents'.